# How to prove the equality of the floors of two expressions?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was doing this problem from Olimpiada de Mayo (Argentina)
[problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJnMmoAjZjKHJLsngZ25pn2XJOhMgeh8/view?usp=drivesdk)
when I wonder if
$$
\bigg\lfloor\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}\bigg\rfloor = \bigg\lfloor\frac{-1+\sqrt{9+8n}}{2}\bigg\rfloor
$$
if $n\geq 3$ and $9+8n$ isn't a perfect square.

Comment: $LHS(5.5)=2$ and $RHS(5.5)=3$ thus not equality.

Comment: $n\geq 3$ is integer and $9+8n$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: You should mention that $n$ is integer in the body of the question.

Comment: $5.5\gt3$ and $9+8\times 5.5=53$

Comment: I was refered to $n=5.5$ Maybe your are right about the condition $n$ integer, I don't know.

Comment: @Piquito The OP writes in the comment that $n$ is integer. I do not know why you decided to communicate with me instead of him/her.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: You're right. It's a collateral problem from another: "I have to do a list of positive integers, equal or not, with the condition that every number in the list have has a value equal to the numbers in the list different from it. For example, if 15 is in the list, there are exactly 15 numbers in the list different from it".  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJnMmoAjZjKHJLsngZ25pn2XJOhMgeh8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: user1729 You're right. And such questions would get no uptake if answerers, like @Will Jagy, in this case, choose not to answer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no odd square strictly between $1+8n$ and $9+8n$ in any case. When there is also no even square between the two numbers, (and the larger one not a square) the two square roots have the same integer part.

When $$ 1+8n < 4 m^2 < 9 + 8n   $$
we find
$$  1+8n = 2m - \delta \; , \; \; \;  9+8n = 2m + \epsilon \; ,$$
with
$$ 0 < \delta , \epsilon < 1 $$

This is not as bad as it looks, because of the $-1$ additions. $$  \left\lfloor \frac{2m-1 \pm \delta}{2}\right\rfloor =  \left\lfloor \frac{2m-2}{2}\right\rfloor = m-1 $$

Example, with $n=4$  we get $33 < 36 < 41,$  $\sqrt{33} \approx 5.744 \approx 6 - 0.255 \; , \; \; \; $ $\sqrt{41} \approx 6.403 \approx 6 + 0.403 \; . \; \; \; $ $$ $$
Then $\sqrt{33} -1\approx 4.744 \approx 5 - 0.255 \; , \; \; \; $ $\sqrt{41}-1 \approx 5.403 \approx 5 + 0.403 \; . \; \; \; $ $$ $$
Then $ \frac{\sqrt{33} -1}{2} \approx \frac{5 - 0.255}{2} \approx 2.5 - 0.127 \; , \; \; \; $ $\frac{\sqrt{41}-1}{2}  \approx \frac{ 5 + 0.403}{2} \approx 2.5 + 0.2015 \; . \; \; \; $

and both have $2$ as integer part.